# Test SNMP connection availability

Tags: java, snmp

Is there a way to test SNMP connection availability in java? I am using [Ireasoning](http://ireasoning.com/) api.

```
         try {
            long timeTicks = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (timeTicks > 4294967295L) { timeTicks-= 4294967295L; }
            SnmpTrap trap = new SnmpTrap(timeTicks, new SnmpOID(oid));
            try {
                InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(agentIp);
                agentIp = inet.getHostAddress();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                System.out.println("SendSNMPTrap::sendVersion2c unable to resolve "+agentIp+" to real IP. Exception="+e2.toString());
            }

            trap.addVarBinds(vb.getVarbinds());
            SnmpTrapSender.sendTrap(destHost, port, trap, true, community);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             logger.error("SendSNMPTrap::sendVersion2c Exception="+e.toString());
             result = false;
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to test the availability of any resources to try to use it. You have to deal with failure when you use it anyway. Why write the same code twice? And why try to predict the future?

Comment: Also, to make it explicit: any test that tells you if the resource is available, might become outdated the next second, when you actually try to use it.

Comment: Maybe the test bit is the intended functionality for his program though

Comment: "The wind can blow one way but actually move you in another, and like sailing, you can use the wind in the wrong direction and still get somewhere you want to go."

-Pete Seeger quoted in Whole Earth Review, spring 2001.

Comment: @Recc The best test is still an attempted use.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't throw any exception if there is no SNMP available, it just sends.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INFORM PDU instead of TRAP PDU. This way the Trap Receiver will send you a response back to acknowledge that it has received the INFORM.